# Laravel Custom Wrapper for API Responses

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen, fractals

I am trying to structure my project in `Laravel` just created to use it as a `back-end API`. I want all my responses from `Laravel` to be returned in the `JSON:API` format defined on the official site: https://jsonapi.org/format/

For example:
I have created the following 2 resource files:

1- `php artisan make:resource User`

2- `php artisan make:resource UserCollection --collection`

Two simple resource files, one to return a `resource` and one to return a `collection`.

Now, I would like to return in all my responses the following format:

- In case of `success`

1- The status return code can be `200`, `201` or `202`.

2- The returned response should be similar to the following:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "collins.elody@example.org"
        }
    ],
    "message": null,
    "success": true
}
```

You may be wondering what is the point of passing the `message` key, in this case it is `null` because it would be returning a `collection` of records, that is, **reading**, but in case you needed to **add** a new record, **update** or **delete** one, you would need to pass a message to my `front-end`, in this case I would use that key for that.

Example, **adding** record, response status code `201`:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "message": "Record created succesfully",
    "success": true
}
```

- In case of `failure`

As said here: https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level : *The members data and errors MUST NOT coexist in the same document.*

So, in case of error, I need change `data` key by `errors` key, for example, suppose I am trying to authenticate myself, and the validation fails, in this case, it should turn out like this:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": "E-Mail is required",
        "password": "Password is required"
    },
    "message": null,
    "success": false
}
```

or I just want to return an `error message`, expected output should by:

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "message": "Something is Wrong!",
    "success": false
}
```

So in essence what I need is a global wrapper for all the responses I make from Laravel. I would like to call return in an elegant way as follows:

```
return $this->success($collection);
```

or

```
return $this->success('Done!', 201);
```

So the first thing that came to mind was creating a `trait` and defining the methods you need to then call them from anywhere in `Laravel`

My `Trait`

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait APIResponse
{
    public function success($data, $status = 200) {
        return [
            'data' => $data,
            'success' => in_array($status, [200, 201, 202]) ? true : false,
            'message' => null
        ];
    }

    public function failure($data, $status = 500) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

My `Controller`

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        $collection = new UserCollection(User::all());

        return $this->success($collection);
    }
}
```

But I am not sure it is the right way to do it, please, someone skilled in the field who can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right path, there is two main solutions i would consider best approaches, to handling your exact problem. [Fractal](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/) and [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources), i prefer Fractal due to some design decisions and experience.

I will show an example in fractal, using the [wrapper by Spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal). Firstly create an serializer that will wrap the data as expected.

```
class YourCustomSerializer extends SerializerAbstract
{
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return [
            $resourceKey ?: 'data' => $data,
            'message': null,
            'success': true,
        ];
    }

    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return [
            $resourceKey ?: 'data' => $data,
            'message': null,
            'success': true,
        ];
    }
```

This should be added to your `fractal.php` config, there is published through the `spatie` wrapper.

Transforming your data you need a transformer.

```
class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(User $user)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you can transform your data into the expected format.

```
public function response($data, int $statusCode = Response::HTTP_OK)
{
    return fractal($data, $this->transformer)->respond($statusCode);
}
```

For error codes, you should go to the `Handler.php` and add something similar to this. This is very naive way of doing it, but for know should get you going on error handling, you need to do something with validation exception, status code etc.

```
if ($request->wantsJson()) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
    ], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: I would no do specific messages for "adding a record" or similar, it is a waste of time, just rely on success true or similar

Comment: As to the json api spec, remember this is a very opiniated spec, which adds a lot of structure for the sake of structure, the argument is always you can use clients or similar to consume your API in practice i have never seen it so far. With how far i think you are based on the question, you need to find your own path of do's and dont's. Thou i somehow agree with the spec that structure is nice, just make it your own.

Comment: Wow! @mrhn, thanks for that detailed explanation, I have been reading about the Fractal package, I have never read about it, as I have read so far, it was used before Laravel version 5.5, as it made this kind of work much easier. I will try to use Eloquent Resources, since it is the official way in which Laravel deals with this type of problem ... if it does not get results, I promise that I will try Fractal then and I will tell you about my experiences. Again .. a million thanks for giving a north to my question.-

Comment: Luckily the approaches are similar thou EloquentResources does not have a similar concept to serializers